# How do I use a variable for a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

In my Rails app, I have the following method:

```
def navigation_menu(items)
  # raise items.class.to_s
  # raise items.to_yaml
  render partial: 'global/navigation_menu', locals: items
end
```

If I uncomment the first line of the method, "Hash" is shown for the exception text, proving that `items` is a hash. If I uncomment the second line, the members of the hash are shown, so I also know it's not empty.

That method fails with the following error:

```
comparison of String with :navigation_menu failed
```

If I replace `locals: items` with `locals: { dummy_key: 'dummy value' }`, it works.

Why can't I use my `items` variable in place of an explicit hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote should work, I often proceed this way.

There is a particular case though: Hashes having keys as strings fail to be interpreted correctly. So it's necessary in this case to append `symbolize_keys` to the Hash:

```
  render partial: 'global/navigation_menu', locals: items.symbolize_keys
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a Ruby/Rails newb here, but I had the same problem, :locals is a options hash, so whatever you pass to :locals would be a hash of options... what I mean is for e.g.

you need to code this way, and if you read eloquent ruby, it states why - unless the parameter is the last hash you can omit the braces...

```
render partial: 'global/navigation_menu', :locals => { :items => item }
```

or if you prefer

```
render partial: 'gloabl/navigation_menu', locals: { items: items }
```

the braces have to be there in the either syntax, although I haven't tried NOT using the braces in the first e.g. in the second however, I believe those are required.

hope this helps!

Comment: That's my workaround at the moment. However, I don't want that intermediary `items` variable. `:(` Basically, I'm trying to avoid having to do `local_assigns[:items]`. I suppose I don't understand why I can't pass a hash directly to it rather than having to create one on the spot. `+1` regardless.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to include the arrow '=>' and put it in a hash {} like this:

```
render :partial => "global/navigation_menu", :locals => { :items => items }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are unable to simply pass locals as the second parameter is that you are specifying a hash of options to `render()` - in this case your hash contains `:partial`. If you take a look at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html) and [code](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Rendering.html#method-i-render) for `render`, you'll see that the method is defined as:

```
def render(options = {}, locals = {}, &block)
...
end
```

Now, if you want to shorten the call to render a partial a bit, there is a shortcut when rendering a partial with no options: "If no options hash is passed or :update specified, the default is to render a partial and use the second parameter as the locals hash." You can do the following:

```
render 'global/navigation_menu', items
```

Check out 'Rendering the default case' in the [partials documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html) for more info.